# php : create SoapServer in mvc project?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I want to create a SOAP server in an MVC oroject.

All the training is out of MVC.

How can I create a web service with SOAP for server?

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
  public function actionVirtual()
  {
    $params = array('uri'=>'server.php');
    $server = new \SoapServer(NULL,$params);
    $server->setClass('server');
    $server->handle();
  }
```

iI can't use server.php in an MVC project!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want toturial for create soap for mvc project!

Comment: what is server.php and how is it relevant? P.S. As monamona pointed out, "I want to" is not a question. What are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Symfony there is a knowledge page for this https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/soap_web_service.html

They have an easy example. I guess the logic for your SOAP service is more complex. Then you might think of to replace the service by a facade.
Then you have a simple interface and the facade hides the complex logic.